# KdV and forest dynamics

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, applications

Today on the lection on KdV equation
$$
    u_t - 6uu_x + u_{xxx} = 0
$$ 
I was told that this equation describes forest dynamics. I tried to find something on this topic in the internet but without success (Wikipedia doesn't contain information about such application too). Please help me with a link or tell me about it.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't "fluid dynamics?"

Comment: In Soviet Russia forests are fluid

Comment: @DanielPietrobon yes, I'm sure

Comment: As you say, there appears to be no information on the internet related jointly to the terms "KdV" (or "Korteweg de Vries" etc) and "Forest dynamics" (or "forest", "computational ecology" etc). There are three explanations I can think of: (1) there is a connection, but no one has written about it on the internet or published any papers about it, (2) whoever told you that the KdV equation models forest dynamics was mistaken, or (3) you misheard 'fluid dynamics' as 'forest dynamics'. I will leave you to assign your own relative likelihoods to those possibilities.